# Switching sprites of a object in different rooms

Tags: game-maker

I am creating a character selection which changes the sprites of the main character.

To do this I have an arrow object which the user clicks to change the sprite of the main character.

```
global.Mario = true;
global.PrincessPeach = false;
global.Luigi = false;
global.Bowser = false;

if (mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left)) {
    if (global.Mario = true) {
        Mario = false;
        PrincessPeach= true;
    }

    if (global.PrincessPeach= true) {
        PrincessPeach = true;
        Mario = false;
    }

    if (global.Luigi = true) {
        Luigi = false;
        Bowser = true;
    }

    if (global.Bowser = true) {
        Bowser = false;
        Mario = true;
    }
}
```

Then, on my main character I have a created an event executing code similar to the following:

```
if (global.Mario = true) {
    sprite_index = Mario_NotJumping;
}

if (global.Luigi = true) {
    sprite_index = Luigispr;
}
```

However, when I run my game to test it out, I get the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR in
action number 1
of Create Event
for object Mario_selection:

Push :: Execution Error - Variable Get -5.Mario(100000, -1)
at gml_Object_Mario_selection_Create_0 (line 1) - if (global.Mario = true) {
```

The object `Mario_selection` has the exact create event and same code as the main character. To display changes to the user.

If anyone could help me out, I am fairly new to GameMaker so I have a feeling I'm just misunderstanding global variables.

Comment: Not sure exactl what is going on but basically the error means you're trying to access global.Mario before it has been initialised.  So I'd guess the second batch of code is being run before the first batch of code. Are both objects on screen straight away?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the var global.Mario, has not been declared. In the arrow objects create event put,

```
global.Mario = true;
global.PrincessPeach = false;
global.Luigi = false;
global.Bowser = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i were you, i would save the chosen "image" of the user in 1 simple variable.

Add a few constants;

```
PLAYER_MARIO = 0;
PLAYER_PEACH = 1;
PLAYER_LUIGI = 2;
PLAYER_BOWSER = 3;
```

Then you can use those constants and save them in a global variable;

```
global.player_image = PLAYER_LUIGI;
```

Then you can use those in your objects like so;

```
switch (global.player_image) {
    case PLAYER_MARIO:
        sprite_index = Mario_NotJumping;
        break;
    case PLAYER_PEACH:
        sprite_index = Peach_NotJumping;
        break;
    case PLAYER_LUIGI:
        sprite_index = Luigi_NotJumping;
        break;
    case PLAYER_BOWSER:
        sprite_index = Bowser_NotJumping;
        break;
}
```

The specific error you were getting was because the global variable was not defined at the time of use.

**A better method** by the way, would be something like this - saving all sprite handles into specific variables, then using those.

Define some constants for readability;

```
P_LEFT = 0;
P_RIGHT = 1;
P_JUMP = 2;
```

Then whenever a player switches its character;

```
//When the user switches to peach;
global.player_sprite[P_LEFT] = spr_Peach_Left;
global.player_sprite[P_RIGHT] = spr_Peach_Right;
global.player_sprite[P_JUMPING] = spr_Peach_Jumping;
```

And overwrite;

```
//When the user switches to Luigi;
global.player_sprite[P_LEFT] = spr_Luigi_Left;
global.player_sprite[P_RIGHT] = spr_Luigi_Right;
global.player_sprite[P_JUMPING] = spr_Luigi_Jumping;
```

Then you can code all code like this;

```
if (jumping) {
    sprite_index = global.player_sprite[P_JUMPING];
} else {
    sprite_index = global.player_sprite[P_LEFT];
}
```

Do you understand what i mean? This way you won't need the switch statements everywhere, and just store the chosen sprites in 1 single array at the beginning of the game.

You can then code the game without having to check what player image the player chose.

Also, always define global variables at the beginning of the game. Global variables will always exist in the game, in every room, at any given moment.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `var mario=true;` instead.